# Making Quiz how to allow User to have multiple trys -Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
print("*Space Knowledge Quiz*")
print()
print("Question 1:")
print("Who was the first man to set foot on the Moon?")
print()
print("A): Buzz Aldrin")
print("B): Pete Conrad")
print("C): Neil Armstrong")
print("D): Tony Abbot")
print()
Answer = input("Input your answer here: ")
if Answer in ('C', 'Neil Armstrong','c'): 
  print('!! Great Job !!')
else:
  print("Oops Try Again? [2 Chances Remaining]")
```

# I'd like to User to have another 2 chances unless answered correctly

Comment: As a general PEP8 style tip: you should use lowercase underscore_separated variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop around all of that with a counter variable, which decreases on every wrong try. Use `break` to exit the loop on a correct answer.

Abstract:

```
tries = 3
while tries>0:
    print('...')
    Answer = input('...')
    if Answer in ('correct', 'answers'):
        print('Yay!')
        break
    else:
        print('Noez!')
        tries-=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `for chances in range(n)` before stsrting to get the users input. If the user is right, print great job and end the program. Right after the `for` block, print that the user has no more chances.

Glad that helps to solve the problem. :)

(Note: `n` is the number of chances that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("*Space Knowledge Quiz*")
print()
print("Question 1:")
print("Who was the first man to set foot on the Moon?")
print()
print("A): Buzz Aldrin")
print("B): Pete Conrad")
print("C): Neil Armstrong")
print("D): Tony Abbot")
print()
trials = 3
for i in range(trials):
    Answer = input("Input your answer here: ")
    if Answer in ('C', 'Neil Armstrong','c'):
        print('!! Great Job !!')
        break
    else:
        remaining = trials-i-1
        s = '' if remaining == 1 else 's'
        print("Oops Try Again? [{0} Chance{1} Remaining]".format(remaining, s))
```

Comment: `remaining = trials-i-1` looks pretty ugly, it's better to `trials -= 1` and then print trials.

Comment: @vishes_shell I agree, but I wanted to keep the value of `trials` fixed, e.g. if other questions appear after this one. Otherwise you would have to remember to reset `trials = 3`

Answer (score 0):

```
print("*Space Knowledge Quiz*\n")
print("Question 1:")
print("Who was the first man to set foot on the Moon?\n")
answerCorrect = False
maxTrys = 2
while not answerCorrect and maxTrys > 0:
    print("(A): Buzz Aldrin")
    print("(B): Pete Conrad")
    print("(C): Neil Armstrong")
    print("(D): Tony Abbot\n")
    Answer = input("Input your answer here: ")
    if Answer in ('C', 'Neil Armstrong','c'): 
        print('!! Great Job !!')
        answerCorrect = True
    else:
        maxTrys -= 1
        if maxTrys == 0:
            print("Sorry, you lost...")
        else:
            print("Oops Try Again? [{} Chances Remaining]".format(maxTrys - 1))
```

**Note this solution is for Python 3.x

Comment: This would go infinite until user answers correctly.

Comment: Since you edited, it will go 4 times, so user has 3 additional chances, not 2 as OP wanted.

Answer (score -2):

You have to create a variable "Trys" and "MaxTrys".

Then you put a for-loop around the if-statement, something like this:

```
for Trys in range(1,MaxTrys):
    if Answer in ('C', 'Neil Armstrong','c'): 
       print('!! Great Job !!')
    else:
       print("Oops Try Again? [2 Chances Remaining]")
```

I am not a python-programmer, I'm not sure the syntax is completly righty, but I guess you can see the logic there ;)

The "2" in "2 Chances Remaining" could be replaced by `"MaxTrys - Trys"`. This would update after each try.

Comment: Does not break when the correct answer is chosen and issues a misleading print statement about the remaining trials left